# how to change app icon on android apk file

Tags: android, react-native, expo

When i build my app with expo build:android and when i install my apk file on android mobile, the icon wont show up, its still showing that gray default expo icon.

I am not sure how to acomplish that, soo if anyone can help would be really great..

Here is my app.json file, i think inside that file is all good but still lets see if anyone can help.

```
    {
  "expo": {
    "name": "bkube",
    "slug": "bkube",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "scheme": "bkube",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#FF9032",
      "ldpi": "./assets/splash.png",
      "mdpi": "./assets/splash.png",
      "hdpi": "./assets/splash.png",
      "xhdpi": "./assets/splash.png",
      "xxhdpi": "./assets/splash.png",
      "xxxhdpi": "./assets/splash.png"
    },
    "packagerOpts": {
      "config": "metro.config.js",
      "sourceExts": [
        "expo.ts",
        "expo.tsx",
        "expo.js",
        "expo.jsx",
        "ts",
        "tsx",
        "js",
        "jsx",
        "json",
        "wasm",
        "svg",
        "png"
      ]
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your location",
        "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your location",
        "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your location"
      },
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.bkube.app"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "package": "com.bkube.app",
      "versionCode": 1,
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
      "permissions": [
        "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
        "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
        "android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"
      ],
      "config": {
        "googleMaps": {
          "apiKey": "*********************************"
        }
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      "expo-notifications",
      "expo-splash-screen",
      "expo-updates",
      "expo-location"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you replaced the desired `icon.png` with the default one in the `assets` folder?

Comment: Of course i did that :D i think its something related to expo, and not my mistake.

Comment: Not sure if the problem is solved? I have this problem too.

Comment: Any updates on this? Have you tried clearing the cache? It might be a solution
https://forums.expo.dev/t/how-to-clear-the-expo-and-react-native-packager-caches-metro-watchman-haste/1352